# How can I re-position status bar icons I'm not running in my configs

Tags: ubuntu, window-manager, i3

I am currently learning how to customize my Ubuntu (20.04) laptop, and I currently use i3, i3status and Polybar. But I am getting status icons in my status bar while I don't have them configured as such. (sometimes in i3status, but mostly in polybar).

[image]

The network icon on the far right is what I'm getting while I have nothing related to that (or other) icons in my config files.

I3Status config

```
general {
    output_format = "dzen2"
    colors = true
    interval = 5
}

order += "tztime local"

tztime local {
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    timezone = "Europe/Amsterdam"   
}
```

Polybar Config

```
[bar/mybar]
modules-center = date
modules-right = battery
background = ${colors.base}
font-0 = JetBrainsMono Nerd Font:style=Regular:size=12

[global/wm]
include-file = ~/.config/polybar/macchiato.ini

[module/date]
type = internal/date
interval = 5.0
date = " %Y-%m-%d %H:%M "

[module/battery]
label-full = "  %percentage%% "
label-charging = "  %percentage%% "
type = internal/battery
full-at = 99
low-at = 10
format-full-background = ${colors.pink}
format-full-foreground = ${colors.base}
format-charging-background = ${colors.pink}
format-charging-foreground = ${colors.base}

[settings]
screenchange-reload = true
```

Macchiato.ini is filled with colors only.

```
;-------------------------
; Catppuccin Macchiato Palette
; Maintainer: justTOBBI
;--------------------------

[colors]
 base = #24273a
 mantle = #1e2030
 crust = #181926

 text = #cad3f5
 subtext0 = #a5adcb
 subtext1 = #b8c0e0

 surface0 = #363a4f
 surface1 = #494d64
 surface2 = #5b6078
 
 overlay0 = #6e738d
 overlay1 = #8087a2
 overlay2 = #939ab7
 

 blue = #8aadf4
 lavender = #b7bdf8
 sapphire = #7dc4e4
 sky = #91d7e3
 teal = #8bd5ca
 green = #a6da95
 yellow = #eed49f
 peach = #f5a97f
 maroon = #ee99a0
 red = #ed8796
 mauve = #c6a0f6
 pink = #f5bde6
 flamingo = #f0c6c6
 rosewater = #f4dbd6

 transparent = #FF00000
```

Comment: That seems to be an icon showing the signal strength of a wireless network. Are you not using wireless networking?

Comment: I am on a wireless network, but I don't know why the icon is showing while I don't have anything related to networking in my configs

Comment: Can you post a link to your config files?

Comment: I've added them in the question @Stephan

Comment: I don't see anything related to networking either. Can you interact with that icon using a right mouse button and does it bring up menu? Can you also post what is in `~/.config/polybar/macchiato.ini`?

Comment: I've updated the question to also include macchiato.ini. And yes, I can interact with the statusbar icons. Today, the icons are in my i3status bar instead of polybar.

Comment: Since there is nothing in the configs of your bar programs and you can interact with icon, it is possible it is from an external program that has its own system tray icon. One such program is `nm-applet`, which is commonly included in the default i3 config file to auto start. Look in `~/.config/i3/config` for any `exec` lines. Also, open the icon menu and look for any "About" entry that may let you know the program name.

Comment: A default Ubuntu install will have the `network-manager-gnome` package installed, which includes the `nm-applet` program. There is an XDG auto start file at `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`. Remove this file and the `exec` line in the i3 config or remove the package altogether.